# Control changes in Google Spreadsheet using Python

Tags: google-sheets, watchdog

I need to control Google Sheet and fix any changes made in it.
Are there any libs like watchdog to do it?

I've tried to use watchdog, but it doesnt work with it.
Or should I create my own handlers?

What are the best ways to connect Python with GoogleDocs?